# Mysql - where last X number are certain value

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

Lists:
id, type, date

Is there a way just in MySQL to return a count on the most recent (order by date desc) where type = '1', but limit by 3?

So the question is, are the last 3 items of value type '1'?

Answer (score 1):

Last 3 dates of type 1, in reverse `date` order:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   type = 1
ORDER BY
        date DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Last 3 dates of type 1, in `date` order:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   type = 1
        ORDER BY
                date DESC
        LIMIT 3
        ) q
ORDER BY
        date
```

Number of contiguous type 1 items in reverse `date` order:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
WHERE   (date, id) >
        (
        SELECT  date, id
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   type <> 1
        ORDER BY
                date DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Count of items with type of 1 in the most recent 3 entries in table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT type FROM mytable ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3
) as t1
WHERE t1.type = 1;
```

I think this is what you are after.